# How to use SagePay with Spree Gateway gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree, activemerchant

I keep getting the following when trying to use SagePay:

```
! '4000 : The VendorName is invalid or the account is not active.'
```

I'm not sure whether there's a problem with the code or the details I'm using, could someone please confirm exactly what details need to go in the fields in the payment method backend, i.e. what goes in login/account and where these details come from.

The login I'm using currently is a developer account.

Spree 1.0.0, spree_gateway 1.0.0 and Rails 3.1.3

Comment: Chris, are you trying to use: SagePay - GB or Sage Payment Solutions - US, CA?

Comment: It's a SagePay UK as far as I am aware...

Answer (score 0):

Try registering for a simulator account here:

https://support.sagepay.com/apply/RequestSimAccount.aspx

Comment: Thanks Adam, I've already done this, not quite sure what to put in the login and account fields in the backend tho, I've tried the vendor name in both and get the same error...

Comment: @ChrisEdwards What was the solution in the end for what to put in the backend? Struggling with this

Comment: @askl56 I think actually it turned out to be a problem with the account / something Sagepay side. It was so long ago and the project no longer exists

Comment: @ChrisEdwards thanks. The Spree::Gateway docs leave a lot to the imagination